# Option loop not found in video input using ffmpeg

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg

I'm trying to merge a image to a video using `ffmpeg`.

This command works to me: `ffmpeg -i merged-video.mp4 -loop 1 -i resized-image.png -shortest -c:a copy out.mp4`

But it's not working when I do it in node.js, using `fluent-ffmpeg`.

My code is like this bellow:

```
const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');

ffmpeg()
    .addInput(mergedVideo)
    .loop(1)
    .addInput(image)
    .audioCodec('copy')
    .outputOptions([
        '-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p',
        '-shortest'
    ])
    .on('error', err => reject(err.message))
    .on('end', resolve)
    .save(finalResultVideo);
```

But it's getting error `ffmpeg exited with code 1: Option loop not found.`

Comment: Likely, node.js applies the options after addInput to that input so move loop to after the image input.

Comment: Hey @Gyan, I tried, but it just got infinite loop if I put loop after `addInput(image)`.